# Change Delimiter using pyspark and save it as textfile in HDFS

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a input data file in HDFS. I will be reading that file and perform some validations like below one. After performing validations i am getting the result as below. I want to change the delimiter of comma to '\t' using pyspark and store it in HDFS. Can any one help me with this. (No csv ans please). Thanks in advance.

```
Validation Code:
dc = data_f.filter("age > 25").filter(data_f.mar == '"married"').groupBy("job","edu").avg("bal","age").sort(data_f.job.desc(),"edu").rdd.map(list).collect()

Result:
  [[u'"unknown"', u'"primary"', 1515.974358974359, 48.61538461538461], 
  [u'"unknown"', u'"secondary"', 1314.2045454545455, 47.84090909090909], 
  [u'"unknown"', u'"tertiary"', 2328.64, 51.84],
  [u'"unknown"', u'"unknown"', 1977.1157894736841, 51.694736842105264], 
  [u'"unemployed"', u'"primary"', 1685.6097560975609, 44.957317073170735], 
  [u'"unemployed"', u'"secondary"', 1472.3518072289157, 43.8433734939759], 
  [u'"unemployed"', u'"tertiary"', 1865.968992248062, 41.031007751937985], 
  [u'"unemployed"', u'"unknown"', 859.1875, 45.375], 
  [u'"technician"', u'"primary"', 1512.704, 47.912]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You need to avoid

```
.csv.write
```

method, you could just use this snippet on rdd

```
def concatenate_row(row):
    concatenated_row = ""
    for col in row:
        concatenated_row += str(col) + "\t"
    return concatenated_row

result = rdd.map(lambda row : concatenate_row(row))
```

and then just call

```
saveAsTextFile
```

method on it